# How to stop all the processes except by entering Linux via SSH?

Tags: 7

I have been deleting some [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) through the Feeds GUI, but somehow Drupal 7 has been stuck. The site is in maintenance mode. I have no Drush access, and I cannot enter with Admin 0 user.

How can I stop all the processes except by entering Linux via SSH?

Comment: I would recommend deleting the contents of the flood table. If you can't log into the site using UID1, it might be wise to [clear the flood table](https://www.drupal.org/node/1023440) before doing anything else. If you reset the password, the flood table will stop any login attempts with the admin account.

Comment: I killed all the processes in the phpMyAdmin. The table involved was *url_alias*. An attemp to change watchdog tablename to watchdog2 produced no results, so finally had to look for any MySQL hangs. I wonder what could I do if it is the PHP hung, maybe resetting httpd ?

Comment: If the HTTPD process has hung, I would recommend restarting it and see if the site comes up. I **do not** recommend renaming any core tables like _watchdog_ or _url alias_ because that will cause you more grief than it will solve. It sounds like you are talking about two different things here as well: the server processes and Drupal itself.

Comment: Admin user "***0***"??? really? That smells like "anonymous" ... Try with "user/1" instead ...

Comment: Yes, Pierre, admin/1, somehow my mind betrait me. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you can log into your hosting account control panel, you may have access to PHPMyAdmin to change the password. Also you might be able to reboot your server from there.

Comment: In Drupal 7, however, it isn't as easy to change the password directly since the [salt hash is also in play](https://www.drupal.org/node/1023428).